# VueJS: Setting img src links for dev mode and production mode

Tags: vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Having trouble loading images in my Vue.js app.

Given that I have:

```
<img :src="imgSrc" />
```

This works in development mode:

```
data() {
  return {
    imgSrc: require('../assets/MyLogo.png'),
  }
}
```

And this works in production mode:

```
data() {
  return {
    imgSrc: '/sites/burnley/assets/MyLogo.png',
  }
}
```

But how can I have this setup so that i can use the same codebase without having to comment in/out lines when I build for production?

Additional:
I've tried this:

```
data() {
  return {
    imgSrc: this.prodMode ? '/sites/burnley/assets/MyLogo.png' : require('../assets/MyLogo.png'),
  }
}
```

but this gives me no link at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to assets this way:

```js
require('@/assets/MyLogo.png');
```

Comment: This works fine in dev mode, but will not work for production mode where I require a different path.

Comment: Seems strange.. did you build the site for production and refer to public as your root directory in production?

Comment: that works for dev, but when I build for production it gives me the wrong path (it concats '/assets/MyLogo.png' on to the `publicPath` set in vue.config.js)

Answer (score 0):

do something like the following:

```
data() {
  return {
    imgSrc: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/sites/burnley/assets/MyLogo.png' : require('../assets/MyLogo.png'),
  }
}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: As I said above, that gives me no link at all in either mode.